# Inserting Images In-line into Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: image, excel

Is it possible to insert images into an Excel spreadsheet automatically given a link to the image?

Comment: The answer is "yes"... but we need to know more about the specific tools/languages/libraries you have before it's possible to explain "how"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it it in Ruby:

The Worksheet object's Shapes collection includes an `AddPicture()` method that creates a picture from an existing file and returns a Shape object that represents the new picture. The syntax is:

```
.AddPicture(Filename, LinkToFile, SaveWithDocument, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

All seven arguments are required, but this allows you to specify the position and size of the picture in the method call.

The following code inserts an image into the range of cells from C3 to F5 in the active worksheet:

```
require 'win32ole'

xl = WIN32OLE.connect('Excel.Application')
ws = xl.ActiveSheet

range = ws.Range('C3:F5')

pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture( { 
    'FileName' => 'C:\Pictures\Image1.jpg', 
    'LinkToFile' => false, 
    'SaveWithDocument' => true, 
    'Left' => range.Left, 
    'Top' => range.Top, 
    'Width' => range.Width, 
    'Height' => range.Height 
} )
```